# What is the best way to implement a Hash rotation method in C++?

Tags: c++, hash

I'm trying to understand hash tables and hash methods (such as division and multiplication), and I was wondering how to implement a rotation method when keys are serial. Say I had a function named `int rotation(int value)` and I had a integer like `int test = 123456`, and I wanted to get the result 612345. What would be the best way to implement this universally (lets say with a text file of 1000 integer groups)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
int rotate(int value)
{
    bool isNegative = value < 0;
    if(isNegative)
        value = -value;
    int v = value % 10;
    value /= 10;
    while(v < value)
        v *= 10;
    value += v;
    return isNegative ? -value : value;
}
```

This will rotate your numbers according to their number of ciphers (123 gets 312, 1234 gets 4123).

For the file part: You would have to open it, read the values, convert them to int and call the function:

```cpp
::std::ifstream in("filename");
if(in.fail())
{
    // error
}
else
{
    int n;
    for(;;)
    {
        in >> n;
        if(in.eof() || in.fail())
            break;

        ::std::cout << rotate(n) << ::std::endl;
    }
    in.close();
}
```